# Dockerfile RUN command - no such file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a problem running an executable in my Dockerfile.
It contains a command to download the 'gsoap' library from an internal service, then the following:

```
ENV PATH="/opt/tools/gsoap/v2.7.12/lnx_x64/bin:${PATH}"
RUN ls -la /opt/tools/gsoap/v2.7.12/lnx_x64/bin
RUN whereis soapcpp2
RUN ["soapcpp2", "-v"]
```

The ls command returns a result:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Mar  1 17:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4096 Mar  1 17:34 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  610652 Mar  1 17:34 soapcpp2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4270809 Mar  1 17:34 wsdl2h
```

And `whereis` is happy too:

```
soapcpp2: /opt/tools/gsoap/v2.7.12/lnx_x64/bin/soapcpp2
```

But trying to run it gives:

```
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Whats going on here?

If I change to use the shell form:

```
RUN soapcpp2 -v
```

I get

```
/bin/sh: 1: soapcpp2: not found
```

Huh? `whereis` just told me its happy that `soapcpp2` is on the PATH.

Answer (score -1):

You need to copy your files in your Dockerfile, using either

`ADD`

or

`COPY`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add

and

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

By the way, you seem to misuse RUN, maybe your last command should be either

a

`CMD`

or

`ENTRYPOINT`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

See also

[What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile?rq=1)

Comment: As stated in the question: `It contains a command to download the 'gsoap' library from an internal service, then the following`

Comment: Post the whole Dockerfile

Comment: see also https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/ you should group your `RUN` to avoid various problems